# Which Stack Exchange to use for privacy questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/intuitive-explanation-of-the-varepsilon-parameter-in-differential-privacy) on [differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy) earlier today, and I wasn't sure where to post it.

- Information Security has a [privacy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) tag with lots of questions (1000+), but only 2 about differential privacy.
- Stack Overflow also has a [privacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/privacy) tag, also quite successful (600+ questions), but only 2 about differential privacy.
- Cross Validated has a [differential-privacy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-privacy) tag, and 4 relevant questions.
- Cryptography has a [differential-privacy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-privacy) and a [data-privacy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-privacy) tag, and 8 questions that mention differential privacy. The 8 questions include [mine](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44739/intuitive-explanation-of-the-varepsilon-parameter-in-differential-privacy), I picked it because of the relevant tags & similar questions.

I'm not sure what's the correct way to proceed, nor whether there is a decision algorithm for similar questions.

Comment: It's going to depend on the specific question that you're asking in that field.

Comment: The decision algorithm would be: `foreach site: read help center(site); if question is on-topic for site: ask; break;`
The types of on-topic questions for the different SE sites are usually pretty mutually exclusive. The alternative would be to be more specific about the question and someone's going to be able to help here.

Comment: @Keiwan: None of the Help Centers of the sites in my question mention privacy. Stack Overflow is more generic, but my question doesn't seem to be on-topic there either.

Comment: @Servy: the specific question I'm asking is linked in my question. I've added a second link, since maybe people missed it.

Comment: The help center doesn't mention Python, but that doesn't mean it's off topic here. Think about the category your question falls into and compare that to the help center info.

Comment: Also check the tour on each of those sites. That will tell you who the target audience is for each SE and what their goal is. You'll want to ask where you're in the target audience and asking your question would advance the site's goal.

Comment: These answers (and the downvotes) make it look like the answer is obvious, but I must be missing something. Information Security *only* mentions security-related questions, of which my question isn't. Same for Crypto with cryptography-related questions, and cross-validated with stats/probability questions. Stack overflow is about *programming*, and my question isn't about programming either. Despite that, questions about privacy have been sucessfully asked here and there. I also thought about cstheory, but my question isn't a research-level question, so it seems off-topic there too.

Comment: Also, considering the number of downvotes, I assume I must be doing something wrong: it would be helpful if somebody would tell me what. My question looks like it falls exactly within what is on-topic for the `site-recommendation` tag on meta.SO, and I gave as much details on my question as I could, since I linked to its full text… What could I do better for next time?

Comment: @Ted I agree that this seems like a valid question for the [meta-tag:site-recommendation] tag. I'm also not sure why this is getting close votes as "unclear what you're asking", seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Did you check that by the way ? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27334/what-is-%CE%B5-in-differential-privacy?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but the questions are different: I know the formal definition of $\varepsilon$, but I can't explain it in simple terms or make it understandable for a non-specialist. While the user who asked this other question apparently had no idea on the subject matter, so the accepted answer is the formal definition that is easy to find & that everybody uses.

Answer (score 5):

As someone with only an interested coder's knowledge of crypto, it seems likely that you asked on the best site. Crypto SE is quite good at handling theoretical questions about cryptographic constructs, so a question with almost any field of application can fit in there as long as it primarily involves crypto.

Cross-Validated and to some extent InfoSec could probably do a decent job as well, as there is some direct professional connection, even though most stats or IT security experts would probably have no personal experience with differential privacy at this point.

SO would be very dubious: there's some potential relevance to a programmer to knowing the meaning of the epsilon parameter, and therefore there are likely some programmers who already do know it, but likewise there are a number of other occupations that have a similar or better need for the knowledge. Fundamentally, it's the sort of thing that really works better when considered as domain-specific business logic, and theoretical questions about the proper ramifications of business logic are very poorly suited for SO. (Incidentally, a good hint as to suitability in this particular case is that SO does not support MathJax.)

Answer (score 4):

As a Security Stack Exchange moderator, when the privacy question is about compliance with or application of regulations (GDPR, DPA, etc.) then those questions should be directed to [Law.StackExchange.com](https://law.stackexchange.com).

There are lots of implementation details about privacy regulations that are not compliance-based, but when it comes to compliance, then regulatory experts need to weigh in under the appropriate context.

Our [Meta discussion about GDPR questions](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/where-do-we-want-to-stand-on-gdpr-questions), specifically, offers some boundaries as to what belongs on Security and what belongs on Law.

Comment: It would be nice if [questions like my one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270656/does-google-maps-widgets-process-location-data-ephemerally) would be migrated instead of closed. I don't understand why people not even have time to say it belongs to law.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: Your question doesn't belong on Law Stackexchange. Why are you jumping to that conclusion?

Comment: @MartinBraun Separately, why are you complaining _here_ instead of flagging your post and/or asking about it on a _relevant_ meta site?  Also, you can just migrate it yourself by copy-pasting.

Comment: @schroeder Could you please tell me what the correct site for my question is? I wasn't sure either, I assumed law, but I didn't feel confident enough to migrate by copy-pasting and potentially jumping into the next pitfall.

Comment: @RyanM-Regenerateresponse I will flag my question, thanks. I fully agree that it makes more sense. I'm still happy to receive a proper response, I'm not sure flagging can give me the same experience.

Comment: @MartinBraun You could ask on Law.SE meta about your question's applicability, or a [site-recommendation] question on Meta.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of privacy-related questions, it seems security.stackexchange.com is the place to go.

Privacy is strongly related to security:

- Being able to access user email addresses can be used to take over user accounts
- Being able to read ids of objects can be used to list all the objects in the database
- Being able to get user locations can be used to find the users, which they might not want
- etc.

Comment: The Wikipedia page linked suggests that "differential privacy" is a specific technical term in cryptography, rather than something from the general field of information security